# jQuery mobile prefetching a page that load content via Ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile in single page template (Each page is a separate html file). I want to prefetch a page that load content via Ajax. I put the prefetch code in Document.ready() function in first page

```
$.mobile.loadPage("my-projects.html", { showLoadMsg: false });
```

ajax call inside the Document.ready() function of second page which i want to prefetch. This ajax call is not happening when we preftech that page. Is there a way to achieve this. Please help

Comment: I think you have to do this using the phonegap events instead of the jQuery-mobile events. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Mobile has prefetching built right in, all you have to do is add the `data-prefetch` attribute to a link that links to a remote page:

```
<a href="prefetchThisPage.html" data-prefetch> ... </a>
```

*Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-cache.html*

In a general sense, when you pull-in a page via AJAX, the `document.ready` function **will not** fire. You can however use jQuery Mobile Page events such as `pageinit`. For example:

```
$(document).delegate('#my-page-id', 'pageinit', function () {
    $.mobile.loadPage("my-projects.html", { showLoadMsg: false });
});
```

Comment: As i am using each page is a separate html file #my-page-id has no relevance here.Also there is no problem with " $.mobile.loadPage("my-projects.html", { showLoadMsg: false }); "  it is firing properly. The problem is with the ajax call which is in the page i want to prefetch.that is not firing when prefeching happends

Comment: You should read this, notice the yellow box: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html. Now in jQuery Mobile since all pages by default are brought into the DOM via AJAX, using an ID to bind to a specific page **certainly does have relevance**. Using code like I showed in my answer allows us to run specific code for specific pages while maintaining one source for our JS (you can put your JS in a file and include it in the head of each page so it's ready for each page). And your problem is `document.ready`, don't use it for jQuery Mobile sites. It won't work like you expect.